# HTML can not show image, how to write image path?

Tags: html

An image is displayed correctly if I save the image in the same folder with the html file.

```
<div class="screenshot"><img src="app.png" alt="This is a screenshot"></div>
```

If I save the image into a different folder called images (parallel level folder with the html folder), then the image can not be displayed.

```
src="images/app.png"
```

The problem must be the wrong path, So what is the problem in above path?

Comment: if images is parallel to html, then you need `../images/etc..."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the following dir structure:

```
/
|-- html/
    |-- yourfile.html
    |-- kitty.jpg
    |-- pics/
        |-- puppy.jpg
|-- images/
    |-- app.png
```

All of the following inside `yourfile.html` would show you images:

```
<img src="kitty.jpg">
<img src="pics/puppy.jpg">
<img src="../images/app.png">
```

If I understand your post correctly, the last line is your case.

Answer (score 0):

`src="images/app.png"` means look in the images folder within the current folder for an image named app.png. If the folders are siblings, try `src="../images/app.png"` where the `..` means traverse up one level.

Answer (score 0):

if your html folder is not the rout folder of your project you have to use this path:
  `<img src="../images/app.png">`
the two dots takes you back to rout folder.

Answer (score 0):

The path for images (or any external file such as .mp4, .pdf, .jpg) is directly relational to where the requesting page is located. To help me remember when I need to use ../ and how many, I think of stairs with landings. I need to have my file on the same "landing" as the series of folders I need to travel down to access the image or file.

```
    _media (folder)
        _images (folder)
            common (folder)
                app.png (image)
            navigational (folder)
    contentA (folder)
        contentA.html (html)
        image.png (image)
    index.html (html)
```

So, if you are working on index.html and need to include the app.png image, you would include it as:

```
    <img src="_media/_images/common/app.png" />
```

This is because the index.html file and the _media folder are on the same "landing". However, if you are working on a file inside a folder that is accessed from an index.html file, then you have to change the path to include the image. For example, if I wanted to include the app.png image on the contentA.html located in the contentA folder, the path to the image you would include is:

```
    <img src="../media/_images/common/app.png" />
```

The ../ means to move up one file from the current level. (Go up to the same landing.) Since contentA.html is in the folder contentA, we need to move up to be equal with index.html in order to move to _media.

Finally, you would not have to back up a step if the file and the image are in the exact same folder. For example, if I wanted to include the image.png image on the contentA.html located in the contentA folder, the path to the image you would include is as originally presented in the question:

```
    <img src="image.png" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Move the images folder into your HTML folder.